# derivative of an objective function with trace of the matrix

Tags: derivatives, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

How can you derive the gradient of 
$$f_{\mu}(U) = \mu \log (\mathbf{Tr}\exp(A+U)/\mu) -\mu \log n$$

as

$$f_{\mu}(U) = (\mathbf{Tr}(A+U)/\mu)^{-1} \exp(A+U)/\mu$$
where $A,U$ are symmetric matrices and $\mu$ is constant.

When taking derivative of $\mathbf{Tr}\exp(A+U)/\mu$ by chain rule, why does it get $\exp(A+U)/\mu$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience, let $T = {\rm tr}(\exp(U+A))$.

Then the function and its differential can be written as
 the variables
$$\eqalign{
  f &= \mu\log(T) -\mu\log(\mu) - \mu\log(n) \cr\cr
 df &= \mu\,\,d\log(T) \cr
    &= \mu\,\frac{dT}{T} = \frac{\mu}{T}\,dT \cr
    &= \frac{\mu}{T}\,\exp(U+A):dU \cr\cr
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial U} &= \frac{\mu}{T}\,\exp(U+A) \cr
    &= \frac{\mu\,\exp(U+A)}{{\rm tr}(\exp(U+A))} \cr
}$$
where I have used the following fact about the differential of the trace of a scalar function applied to a matrix argument
$$\eqalign{
 d\,{\rm tr}(f(X)) = f'(X^T) : dX
}$$